# I'm looking for some clarity on the phrase "went in ignorance of."

Tags: idioms

The following sentence is taken from *The War of the Worlds* by H. G. Wells.
I can understand the phrase ***went in ignorance of***, but I am wondering if it is an idiomatic expression.

> Yet the next day there was nothing of this in the papers except a
>   little note in Daily Telegraph, and the world **went in ignorance of**
>   one of the gravest dangers that ever threatened the human race.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it was idiomatic, although it would be considered old-fashioned today. It's just rather typical of late 19th century English writing. Stylistically, Wells was a very conventional writer.

Comment: An ordinary meaning of the verb *to go*, meaning to proceed. Check the google and you'll find plenty of occurrences of the locution "went through life". So people simply proceeded to conduct their lives unaware of the threat.

Comment: @deadrat Yes. I don't consider that idiomatic use of *go* as at all old-fashioned, as has been suggested. *Lost in the desert they had gone without food for a week*. *He went in search of his long-lost friend*.  *On a deserted stretch of beach they had gone naked*. *It goes without saying that he should have known better*. Indeed the terms *gone mad*, or *went berserk* are examples of related senses of *go*. *And that goes for you too!*

Comment: @WS2 It's a long time since I've heard the phrase *went in ignorance* (probably when I last read Wells). *Remained in ignorance*  would be much more current.

Comment: @Mick Yes, I think I agree with you there. I didn't realise you were referring to that specific phrase. I now note that you are a UK chap. Problem is with the site you are never quite sure who you are talking to. I had it in mind that you may have been objecting to that sense of *go*.

Comment: @WS2 I've been trying to think of a more modern phrase and failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mick I think your suggestion of *remained in ignorance* was a good one. But possibly  *lived in ignorance, proceeded in ignorance, carried on in ignorance...*? Of course there's nothing wrong with *went in ignorance*. I would not be surprised to hear it used.

Answer (score 1):

If we compare the frequency of *"went in ignorance"* with, say, *"remained in ignorance"* using Google Books, we get the following chart for the past two centuries:

[image]

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+in+ignorance%2Cremained+in+ignorance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20in%20ignorance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremained%20in%20ignorance%3B%2Cc0)

As you can see, *went in ignorance* barely makes an appearance whilst *remained in ignorance* was much more common in the past, although it usage has steadily declined throughout the 20th century.

There's nothing wrong with Wells's writing style; in fact he was very conventional. He wrote *War of the Worlds* in 1897 and his turn of phrase is so economical that it sounds as if he lifted it straight from Jane Austen. However, the only other occurrence that I can find is in Agnes Repplier's *Pere Marquette: Priest, Pioneer and Adventurer*, which was published in 1929.

> It cannot be said that the French missionaries went in ignorance to
>   meet their fate. The Jesuit Relations are as outspoken as any
>   narratives ever given to the world.

So maybe Wells coined the phrase and a few others saw fit to borrow it, but I'm not sure that we can call it idiomatic. The meaning is clear enough and it has no need of explanation.

[Agnes Repplier, *Pere Marquette: Priest, Pioneer and Adventurer*, 1929](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KduN6Os4VZYC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22went+in+ignorance%22&source=bl&ots=HnXZDqNwG5&sig=xFF5RqboXKncdJXnIqfZHgeW3ck&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEzNj3icbPAhVqCsAKHS_pA8YQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22went%20in%20ignorance%22&f=false)